# Relational Algebra : Cross Product of a Relation with Table-Dum & Table-Dee

Tags: relation-algebra

I am wondering what would be the result of the following operation:

Let $A$ be a relation with $n$ ($n > 0$) attributes and $t$ ($t > 0$) tuples. 
Let $TableDum$ be a relation with $0$ attributes and $0$ tuples.
Let $TableDee$ be a relation with $0$ attributes and $1$ tuples.

What would the result of the following be? ($\times$ being the cross product)

$R_1 = A \times TableDum\\
R_2 = A \times TableDee$

Would $R_1$ be a relation with $n$ attributes or $0$ attributes?
Would $R_1$ be a relation with $0$ tuples?
Would $R_2$ be a relation with $n$ attributes or $0$ attributes?
Would $R_2$ be a relation with $0$ tuples?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are your own ideas on this?

Comment: After some research, TableDum is the relational equivalent of true, and TableDee is the relational equivalent of false. R1 would then be equal to A without tuples. R2 would be equal to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A = R_1 \times TableDum = A_(empty)\\
A = R_2 \times TableDee = A 
$$